# Is it better to set contextmenu attribute only as needed?

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm creating an "Open Link in This Tab" context menu item that should appear when any link on a given webpage is right-clicked. The last chunk of my current code adds the attribute to every link:

```
for (let node of document.getElementsByTagName("a")) {
    node.setAttribute("contextmenu", menu.id);
}
```

It occurs to me that I could add the attribute only to those links that are actually right-clicked, like this:

```
for (let node of document.getElementsByTagName("a")) {
    node.oncontextmenu = function() {
        node.setAttribute("contextmenu", menu.id);
    };
}
```

Is there any advantage to doing it one way or the other?

Comment: Consider event delegation: put a single *contextmenu* listener on a parent of all the links, then check to see where the event came from and go from there. If you don't have many links, does it really matter? Oh, and not all A elements are links, some may be anchors. All the links in a document are given by the *document.links* collection so `for (let link of document.links)...`. ;-)

Comment: +1 for `document.links` at the very least. @Shadow is probably right that I'm overthinking this, but I'm still curious: What would you consider to be "many" links? It looks like I may have as many as 300 on some pages.

Comment: @RobG, you were right, event delegation was the way to go. I've rewritten the whole thing accordingly and it works much better. I'd pick your comment as the answer if I could – want to post it as one so I can?

Comment: You can post your own answer and accept it if you like. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per RobG's suggestion above, setting the attribute on the body is better than either of the alternatives I was choosing between – essentially, this:

```
document.body.addEventListener("contextmenu", menuOn);
```

Followed by this:

```
function menuOn() {
    if (document.activeElement.href !== undefined) {
        document.body.setAttribute("contextmenu", menu.id);
    } else {
        document.body.removeAttribute("contextmenu");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In both of your examples, you are adding event handlers to every `a` tag.

In the second example, you use the event handler just to replace itself with the real one. In fact in this scenario I would highly suspect that the first time a user right clicks the behaviour will differ from the intention as it replaces the itself with the intended handler rather than just doing what you want it to do.

In short, I think you are overthinking this. The first example seems lighter and clearer.